# How can I disable Flurry analytics when using their ad network?

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm using Flurry ads on Android and I noticed the app keeps collecting analytics which I am not using. I give my users the option to opt out from analytics, so how can I disable Flurry analytics when the user opts out?

Thanks.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: Nope, never found anything.